# Substituindo valores NaN pelo subsequente not NaN de outra coluna

Tags: python, pandas

Possuo um DataFrame com algumas colunas (estou representando apenas duas neste post). Preciso preencher os NaN de uma das colunas com determinados valores de outra. Veja abaixo:

### Criando o DataFrame de teste

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"base": [2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5], "valores":[3, None, 100, 3, None, None, 15, None]})

>>> df
   base  valores
0     2      3.0
1     2      NaN
2     3    100.0
3     3      3.0
4     4      NaN
5     4      NaN
6     5     15.0
7     5      NaN
```

### A saída que espero:

```
>>> df
   base  valores
0     2      3.0
1     2      3.0   # valor da coluna base referente ao índice 3
2     3    100.0
3     3      3.0
4     4      5.0   # valor da coluna  base referente ao índice 6
5     4      5.0   # valor da coluna base referente ao índice 6
6     5     15.0
7     5      NaN   # nenhum valor posterior
```

Ou seja, para cada valor NaN encontrado, substituir pelo próximo valor válido. No caso do último, caso este seja NaN, mantê-lo.

### O que tentei

Tentei utilizar o método `fillna()` o qual atualizaria os NaN com determinado valor fixo ou o subsequente not-NaN da mesma coluna caso `method='bfill'` conforme abaixo

```
>>> df["valores"].fillna(method='bfill')
0      3.0
1    100.0
2    100.0
3      3.0
4     15.0
5     15.0
6     15.0
7      NaN
```

Também tentei utilizar o método `fillna()` buscando os valores da "base" conforme abaixo:

```
>>> df["valores"].fillna(df["base"])
0      3.0
1      2.0
2    100.0
3      3.0
4      4.0
5      4.0
6     15.0
7      5.0
Name: valores, dtype: float64
```

Entretanto os valores recebidos são do mesmo índice

Preciso juntar as duas funcionalidades ou outra forma para chegar ao resultado.

### Outras ideias

Em tempo: Outro método que pensei que pudesse ajudar é o `isna()` ou `notna()`

```
>>> df["valores"].isna()
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6    False
7     True
Name: valores, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possível criar uma Series temporária apenas com valores da coluna **base** onde **valores** não é nulo com os comandos [`.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html), [`.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) e[`.bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html).
Com essa Series em uma variável é possível passa-la dentro do comando [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna) para substituir os valores da coluna **valores**

```
temp = df['base'].mask(df['valores'].isna()).bfill()
df['valores'] = df['valores'].fillna(temp)
df.head(10)

#saida
    base    valores
0   2       3.0
1   2       3.0
2   3       100.0
3   3       3.0
4   4       5.0
5   4       5.0
6   5       15.0
7   5       NaN
```

---

O comando `mask` aqui retorna uma Series do mesmo tamanho do DF, mas onde a condição for verdadeira (`df['valores'].isna()`) fica como nulo, segue alguns resultados do passo a passo.

### Comando `mask` com `isna`

```
df['base'].mask(df['valores'].isna())
#saida:
0    2.0
1    NaN
2    3.0
3    3.0
4    NaN
5    NaN
6    5.0
7    NaN
```

### Comando `mask`, `isna` e `bfill`

```
df['base'].mask(df['valores'].isna()).bfill()
#saida:
0    2.0
1    3.0
2    3.0
3    3.0
4    5.0
5    5.0
6    5.0
7    NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma possibilidade é cria um dicionário `group` a partir do data frame `df` onde as chaves são os valores sem duplicatas da coluna `base` e os respectivos valores de chave são um dicionário apontando para os índice das linhas de `df` cujo `base` é a chave e `valores` é diferente de `NAN`.

Depois aplique o transformador replace() da primeira a penúltima linha de `df`, transformador esse que aceita três parâmetros:

- `val`: uma linha de para ser transformada.
- `g`: um dicionário definido anteriormente.
- `df`: que é o próprio data frame.

A cada linha de `df` é:

- verificado se a linha `val` contém  algum valor nulo.

  - se sim busca o próximo valor consecutivo válido de `base` pesquisando `g`.
  - Se não encontrar um próximo valor consecutivo de `base` retorna a proporia linha.
  - Troca o valor `NAN` pelo valor adequado cujo o índice está localizado em `g`.

<sub>[Teste o exemplo](https://paiza.io/projects/wG0ukST1M8VMMserXfGqew?language=python3)</sub>

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
    "base": [2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5], 
    "valores":[3, None, 100, 3, None, None, 15, None]
})


def replace(val, g, df):
    if pd.isna(val[1]):
        i= next((k for k in g if k > val[0]), None)
        if i == None:
            return val
        val[1] = df.iloc[g[i][-1:],0]
    return val 
  
  
group = df[df["valores"].notna()].groupby("base").groups             #{2: [0], 3: [2, 3], 5: [6]}
    
df["valores"] = df.transform(replace, 1, group, df)[0:-1]["valores"]

print(df)

#   base  valores
#0     2      3.0
#1     2      3.0
#2     3    100.0
#3     3      3.0
#4     4      5.0
#5     4      5.0
#6     5     15.0
#7     5      NaN
```